# Adding intermediate step after login in FOSUserBundle Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

How to configure FOSUserBundle to add an intermediate step after login. Users should select an account client on a list of accessible accounts. 
Therefore, how to save the selected account client in the security token?

Answer (score 0):

You have to customise the whole FOSUserBundle login process.

See the [Overriding controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html) part of FOSUB documentation

When you have the controller, override the `renderLogin` and `loginAction` methods.
You have to replace the `action` of the login form to be redirected on your custom action (which represents the custom additional step).

And, in your custom step, just login the user by calling the original `action` of the login form.

All can be done by following the [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) and [FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) documentations.